# how to put the condition for rendered attribute when my list has one value in vf page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

i have a pageblock that i want will renderd if my list has one value for this i tried

```
rendered="{!lowesPortalTranscations.size == 1}"
```

and my list has only one value but it is laso rendering when list is null, how i check this condition?

Comment: can you post the code behind your list/ are you limiting the list to 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a boolean attribute in Controller

and based on List size make it true.

```
public boolean displayList {get;set;}
public void prepareList()
{
    List<Account> acctList = [SELECT ...... FROM Account... LIMIT 1];
    if(acctList.size()==1)
    {
        displayList  = true;
    }
}
```

Visualforce

```
<apex:pageblock rendered="{!displayList}">
```

Comment: Thank you santanu it is working perfectly for me.Thanks a  lot!!